# Воспроизведение музыки онлайн, Python

Tags: python, pygame, kivy

я создаю медиаплеер на языке Python, библиотека kivy. Я хочу сделать поиск пользователем названия песни, которую он желает, и запуск ее онлайн, но я не знаю библиотеку, которая может это сделать. Я только знаю, что можно это легко сделать, если будет url ссылка на саму песню в разрешении mp3, но я не нашел ресурсов, которые могут сделать такую ссылку автоматически.  Для запуска музыки я использую pygame, но в этой библиотеке нет функции, которая мне нужна.

Comment: А в чём проблема получить ссылку на песню используя Selenium? Там ведь вроде можно получить значение атрибута у элементов, там спокойно берёте `src` и не паритесь. (Главное сервис найти который позволит получить исходник песни из `src`)

Comment: До этого никогда не слышал просто про src, я могу без селениума сделать парсер, чтобы получить ссылку src, проблема только сейчас в том, что по запросам в гугле всеравно выдает только mp3 формат.

Comment: В теории можно использовать AJAX, но не уверен в выборе

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Пример без использования pygame и requests

import io
from threading import Thread
import pygame
import requests
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.config import Config
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.progressbar import ProgressBar
from kivy.network.urlrequest import UrlRequest

Config.set('graphics', 'width', '300')
Config.set('graphics', 'height', '250')


class App(App):
    progress_bar = None

    def build(self):
        pygame.init()
        pygame.mixer.init()

        self.progress_bar = ProgressBar()

        box_layout_vertical = BoxLayout(
            orientation='vertical',
            size_hint_y=None
        )  # BoxLayout

        play_button = Button(
            text='Eminem - Lose Yourself',
            size_hint_y=None,
            height=40
        )

        play_button.bind(on_press=self.play_button_on_press_handler)

        box_layout_vertical.add_widget(play_button)
        box_layout_vertical.add_widget(self.progress_bar)

        return box_layout_vertical

    def play_button_on_press_handler(self, event):
        Thread(target=self.play_audio).start()

    def get_bytes_mp3(self):
        URL = "http://audio.xmcdn.com/group58/M03/8D/07/wKgLc1zNaabhA__WAEJyyPUT5k4509.mp3"
        #URL = 'https://cdn3.sefon.pro/prev/zlZ2w8X97cVE7irJetLC1w/1657715725/41/Eminem%20-%20Lose%20Yourself%20%28192kbps%29.mp3'

        headers = {
            'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/103.0.0.0 Safari/537.36',

            }

        response = UrlRequest(URL, req_headers=headers)

        response.join()

        print(response.result)
        # response = requests.get(URL, headers=headers, stream=True)

        #value = int(response.headers['Content-Length']) / 100

        # return response.iter_content(chunk_size=int(value))
        return response.result

    def play_audio(self):
        self.progress_bar.value = 0
        bytes_object = io.BytesIO()
        array = bytearray()
        for byte in self.get_bytes_mp3():
            array.append(byte)
            self.progress_bar.value += 1
        # bytes_object.write(byte)
        bytes_object.write(array)

            # print(bytes_object.getbuffer().nbytes)
        bytes_object.seek(0)

        pygame.mixer.music.load(bytes_object)
        pygame.mixer.music.play(-1)


def main():
    App().run()
    pygame.quit()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Большое спасибо, осталось найти способ получать mp3 ссылку. Вы мне очень помогли.

Answer (score 1):

Если не вдаваться в подробности то как то так)

```
import io
from threading import Thread
import pygame
import requests
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.config import Config
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.progressbar import ProgressBar

Config.set('graphics', 'width', '300')
Config.set('graphics', 'height', '250')


class App(App):
    progress_bar = None

    def build(self):
        pygame.init()
        pygame.mixer.init()

        self.progress_bar = ProgressBar()

        box_layout_vertical = BoxLayout(
            orientation='vertical',
            size_hint_y=None
        )  # BoxLayout

        play_button = Button(
            text='Eminem - Lose Yourself',
            size_hint_y=None,
            height=40
        )

        play_button.bind(on_press=self.play_button_on_press_handler)

        box_layout_vertical.add_widget(play_button)
        box_layout_vertical.add_widget(self.progress_bar)

        return box_layout_vertical

    def play_button_on_press_handler(self, event):
        Thread(target=self.play_audio).start()

    def get_mp3_object(self):
        URL = 'https://cdn3.sefon.pro/prev/zlZ2w8X97cVE7irJetLC1w/1657715725/41/Eminem%20-%20Lose%20Yourself%20%28192kbps%29.mp3'

        headers = {
            'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/103.0.0.0 Safari/537.36',

            }

        response = requests.get(URL, headers=headers, stream=True)

        return response.headers['Content-Length'], response.iter_content(chunk_size=76895)

    def play_audio(self):
        bytes_object = io.BytesIO()

        length, content = self.get_mp3_object()

        for byte in content:
            value = int(length) / 100
            print(value)
            self.progress_bar.value += 1
            bytes_object.write(byte)
            # print(bytes_object.getbuffer().nbytes)
        bytes_object.seek(0)

        pygame.mixer.music.load(bytes_object)
        pygame.mixer.music.play(-1)


def main():
    App().run()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Большое спасибо, только я не понимаю зачем выводить количество байт и слайдер

Comment: Для отдладки. А так делайте как хотите. Вообще для работы с аудио есть более продвинутые библиотеки.

Comment: Мне продвинутые особо и не надо, ведь я только загружаю и провожу элементарные действия с музыкой.

Comment: Ну тогда воспроизводите музыку посредством kivy,  раз вы и так используете эту либу, в своём проекте.

Comment: Kivy не взаимодействует с mp3 url, так что pygame будет легче, спасибо

Comment: Вы со мной будете спорить?

Comment: Что значит не взаимодействует с URL ?

Comment: https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.network.urlrequest.html

Comment: https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.core.audio.html

Comment: например есть ссылка http://audio.xmcdn.com/group58/M03/8D/07/wKgLc1zNaabhA__WAEJyyPUT5k4509.mp3 , но я не могу ее воспроизвести с помощью kivy, а могу только через pygame или другую библиотеку.

Comment: да, я находил это, но не уверен, что это будет работать, но тем не менее спасибо, стоит попробовать.